# Select element default/empty option in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

Using `selectFieldList` form fields in Yesod, the behaviour seems to be that if you use `mreq`, there is no default "empty" option for the select element.  If you use `mopt`, the default option (corresponding to a `Nothing` value) has the text `<None>`.

1) How can you change the text for the `<None>` option when using `mopt`?

2) How can I add an empty option while using `mreq`?  The type signature for `selectFieldList` takes`[(msg, a)]` as its argument for the options - so there's no scope there to add a "dummy" option.

Comment: you can always do `[("", Nothing)]`, or exactly what HTML do you want to generate? `<option disabled>..`?